# How to cancel angular service ajax request

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular rest service like this

```
.factory('Store', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource("/stores/:id/:action.json", {
            id : "@id",
            action : "@action",
            longitude : "@longitude"
        });
    } ])
```

And I am call get method in my controller like this:

```
    Store.get({
        id : $stateParams.id,
        longitude: $rootScope.currentLocation.longitude,
        latitude: $rootScope.currentLocation.latitude
    }, function(data) {
        self.original = data;
    }, function(error){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('ServerUnreachable');
    });
};
```

But before it resolve the response, if user left the view I want to cancel the ajax request in my $destroy callback, any idea?

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    // how to cancel
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$resource documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) says:

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.

So, pass an unresolved promise to the $resource call and, in your $destroy callback function, resolve this unresolved promise to abort the request:

```
// create an unresolved canceler
var canceler = $q.defer();
var promiseToPassToResource = canceler.promise;

// to cancel the http call:
canceler.resolve('user left page');
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this example where they pass canceler to the createResourceInstance function, but im not too sure how do I pass my canceler to my .factory('Store', [ '$resource', function($resource) {?

Comment: I never use ngResource, so I don't have much experience with it. It also looks to me like a weird design to pass a single promise to construct a reusable $resource. I guess you'll have to create a new $resource every time rather than using a single one.