# How to abort previously sending a request in angluarjs (MEAN application)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am developing MEAN Stack application.In application, if I click on a link multiple time it sends to server multiple it causes a browser to hang or unresponsive or crash.

Below is code snippet in which I retrieve photos from server.It comes from the server but when I click on links 3 - 4 time then it will response may delay or hang the browser.In this situation, I required aborting previous requests and executes an only current request.

How do I prevent multiple requests sending or if the application allows to sending multiple requests then how to abort previously sending a request? Cna you give me proper solution and code management?

> PhotoController.js

```
    (function () {

        'use strict';
        /**
         * Photo Controller for photo features
         * @param {type} $rootScope
         * @param {type} $scope
         * @param {type} $state
         * @param {type} $timeout
         * @param {type} HzServices
         * @param {type} HzPhotoService
         * @param {type} Upload * @returns {undefined}
         */
        function PhotoCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $state, $window, $routeParams, $timeout, HzServices, HzPhotoService, Upload, HzSocket, notifications) {
            /*
             * Initiliaze custom scrollbar for following features
             * rightside - my album list
             * add/edit album - emoji list
             */
            //Data loads when $viewContentLoaded.
            $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                $scope.counter = 0;
                $scope.currentTab = 'all-photos';
                $scope.init();
                $scope.doAlbumList('', '', '', '', 0, 0);
            });

            // Scroll to top, when page loads
            angular.element("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 0);


            /*
             *Initialize select2 options for email ids
             */
            $scope.init = function () {
                $scope.select2Options = {
                    multiple: true,
                    'simple_tags': true,
                    tokenSeparators: [','],
                    tags: [], // Can be empty list.
                    selectOnBlur: true,
                    formatNoMatches: function () {
                        return '';
                    },
                    dropdownCss: {display: 'none'}
                };
                $scope.myAlbumListConfig = HzServices.initNgScrollbarsConfig();
                $scope.myAlbumEmojiConfig = HzServices.initNgScrollbarsConfig();
                $scope.frmPhoto = null;
                $rootScope.photoIndex = 0;
                // Prevent to sent request to server by continuously click on "All photos"
                $scope.defaultAlbum = null;
                $scope.fullWidthClass = null;
                $scope.albums = {};
                $scope.albumsCount = null;
                $scope.myAlbums = {};
                $scope.myAlbumsCount = null;
                $scope.photos = {};
                $scope.photosByDate = {};
                $scope.photosCount = null;
                //set model variable for photo pagination
                $scope.photoRecordsOffset = 0;
                $scope.photoRecordsTotal = 0;
                $scope.photoYears = [];
                $scope.albumModel = {album_name: "", album_description: "", album_emoji: "", is_auto_generate: 0};
                $scope.myAlbumIsAutoGenerated = 1;
                $scope.photoModel = {};
                $scope.browsePhotoModel = {};
                // Set default global variables of edit album
                $scope.deletedPhotoTotal = 0;
                $scope.deleteFlag = false;
                $rootScope.emojis = {};
                $scope.arrPhoto = [];
                $scope.modelChkBrowsePhoto = {};
                $scope.selectedBrowsePhotoIden = [];
                $scope.selectedBrowsePhotoIndex = [];
                $scope.deSelectedBrowsePhotoIden = [];
                $scope.obsoleteBrowsePhotoIden = [];
                $scope.checkAllFlag = false;
                $scope.overBox = {};
                $scope.deleteBox = {};
                $scope.moveBox = {};
                $scope.overBoxFlag = false;
                $scope.deleteBoxFlag = false;
                $scope.moveBoxFlag = false;
                $scope.currentSelectedPhotoCount = 0;
                $scope.currentMovedPhotoCount = 0;
                $scope.currentDeletedPhotoCount = 0;
                $scope.filesLen = 0;
                $scope.counter = 0;
            };

            /**
             * Lists available albums of user
             * @param {String} pagination
             * @param {String} album
             * @param {Number} recordsPerPage
             * @param {String} selectedTab
             * @param {Boolean} includeMovedPhotos
             * @returns {undefined}
             */
            $scope.doAlbumList = function (pagination, album, recordsPerPage, selectedTab, includeMovedPhotos, includeDeletedPhotos) {
                HzServices.showActiveElementTab();
                angular.element("ul.error-log li").remove();

                //$rootScope.arrData = [];

                /*
                 * Pagination params
                 */
                if (!!pagination && pagination === "VIEWMORE") {
                    $scope.photoRecordsOffset = $scope.photoRecordsOffset + $rootScope.recordsPerPage;
                }

                /*
                 * Following condition is affected specficially when move photo to album and it requires
                 * to display and update photos for those particular photos. There is not requires to update
                 * other photos of an album
                 * When $scope.arrPhoto is blank so it consider, default behaviour of listing, otherwise it lists only
                 * those photos which are listed in edit photos option.
                 */
                var data = {};
                if ($scope.arrPhoto.length === 0) {
                    data = {
                        q: $state.params.pid, // Userid
                        album: album, // album Id
                        // custom records offset used in move album section and update pagination used both recordsPerPage and recordsOffset
                        // records per page
                        recordsPerPage: (!!recordsPerPage) ? recordsPerPage : $rootScope.recordsPerPage,
                        recordsOffset: $scope.photoRecordsOffset,
                        // It includes photos which are moved from source album to destination album but source album reference is also present,
                        // It helps to know which photo is moved from current album to destination album in move album tab.
                        includeMovedPhotos: includeMovedPhotos,
                        includeDeletedPhotos: includeDeletedPhotos
                    };
                } else {
                    data = {
                        pid: $scope.arrPhoto
                    };
                }
                /*
                 * Pagination
                 */
                var deferred = HzServices.deferred("/api/album/list", 'POST', data);
                deferred.then(
                        function (res) {
                            /*
                             * success in repsonse
                             * Share common photo & album data across all controllers, directives by angular custom service.
                             */
                            var data = {album: {count: res.data.count.album, data: res.data.album}, albumWithDeletedPhoto: {count: res.data.count.albumWithDeletedPhoto, data: res.data.albumWithDeletedPhoto}, myAlbum: {count: res.data.count.myAlbum, data: res.data.myAlbum}, myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto: {count: res.data.count.myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto, data: res.data.myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto}, photo: {count: res.data.count.photo, data: res.data.photo}};
                            HzPhotoService.setSharedData(data);
                            if (false === !!$scope.myAlbumName && false === !!$scope.myAlbumId) {
                                $scope.myAlbumName = "All photos";
                                $scope.myAlbumId = "";
                            }
                            //Create an array of magnific inline popup content
                            //HzPhotoService.setInlinePopupContent(data.photo.data);
                            var sharedData = HzPhotoService.getSharedData();
                            //Get all albums list
                            $scope.albums = sharedData.album.data;
                            $scope.albumsCount = sharedData.album.count;
                            //Get all albums with deleted records list
                            $scope.albumsWithDeletedPhoto = sharedData.albumWithDeletedPhoto.data;
                            $scope.albumsWithDeletedPhotoCount = sharedData.albumWithDeletedPhoto.count;
                            //Get my custom albums list
                            $scope.myAlbums = sharedData.myAlbum.data;
                            $scope.myAlbumsCount = sharedData.myAlbum.count;
                            //Get my custom album with deleted records list
                            $scope.myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto = sharedData.myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto.data;
                            $scope.myAlbumWithDeletedPhotoCount = sharedData.myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto.count;

                            // Pagination if required
                            if (pagination === "VIEWMORE") {
                                $scope.photos = $scope.photos.concat(sharedData.photo.data);
                            } else {
                                if ($rootScope.recordsOffset === 0) {
                                    $scope.photos = sharedData.photo.data;
                                }
                            }
                            $scope.photosByDate = HzPhotoService.setSharedDataByDate((pagination === "VIEWMORE") ? true : false);
                            //BrowsePhotoModel to pass all photos lists to directive
                            $scope.browsePhotoModel = $scope.photos;
                            //$scope.uploadResults = $scope.photos;
                            $scope.photosCount = sharedData.photo.count;
                            $scope.photoRecordsTotal = $scope.photosCount;
                            if (selectedTab === "edit_album") {
                                $scope.doToggleSelectAll($scope.checkAllFlag, $scope.photoRecordsOffset);
                            }

                            // Get Emoji list
                            // if (!!HzPhotoService.getSharedEmojis()) {
                            if (0 === Object.keys($rootScope.emojis).length) {
                                $scope.doEmojiList();
                            }
                        },
                        function (res) {
                            /*
                             * Error hading in repsonse
                             */
                            var data = {album: {count: $scope.albumsCount, data: $scope.albums}, albumsWithDeletedPhoto: {count: $scope.albumsWithDeletedPhotoCount, data: $scope.albumsWithDeletedPhoto}, myAlbum: {count: $scope.myAlbumsCount, data: $scope.myAlbums}, myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto: {count: $scope.myAlbumWithDeletedPhotoCount, data: $scope.myAlbumWithDeletedPhoto}, photo: {count: $scope.photosCount, data: $scope.photos}};
                            HzPhotoService.setSharedData(data);
                            notifications.showSuccess({
                                message: "Oops! something went wrong, please try again later.",
                                hideDelay: 3000, //miliseconds
                                hide: true // boolean
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(function (response) {
                            console.error('request error', response.status, response.data);
                        })
                        .finally(function () {
                            console.log("finally finished request");
                        });
            };
            /**
             * get emoji list
             * @returns {undefined}
             */
            $scope.doEmojiList = function () {
                var deferred = HzServices.deferred("/api/emoji/getlist", 'GET');
                deferred.then(
                        function (res) {
                            HzPhotoService.setSharedEmojis(res.data);
                            // console.log($rootScope.emojis);
                            $scope.isEmojiVisible = false;
                        },
                        function (err) {
                            notifications.showSuccess({
                                message: "Oops! something went wrong, please try again later.",
                                hideDelay: 3000, //miliseconds
                                hide: true // boolean
                            });
                        }
                );
            };
        }

        angular
                .module("AppDream")
                .controller('PhotoCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$window', '$routeParams', '$timeout', 'HzServices', 'HzPhotoService', 'Upload', 'HzSocket', 'notifications', PhotoCtrl]);
    }());
```

> HzServices.js

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular
                .module("AppDream")
                .factory("HzPhotoService", ['$rootScope', '$state', 'HzServices',
                    function ($rootScope, $state, HzServices) {
                        var methods = {};
                        var arrData = [];
                        var sharedData = {};
                        var sharedDataByDate = {data: []};
                        var sharedEmojis = {};
                        $rootScope.emojis = {};
                        var setSharedData = function (data) {
                            sharedData = data;
                        };
                        var getSharedData = function () {
                            return sharedData;
                        };
                        var setSharedEmojis = function (data) {
                            //sharedEmojis = data;
                            $rootScope.emojis = data;
                        };
                        var getSharedEmojis = function () {
                            return $rootScope.emojis;
                            //return sharedEmojis;
                        };
                        var setSharedDataByDate = function (isAllowToConcat, photos) {
                            var sharedDataPhotoLength = (!!photos) ? photos.length : sharedData.photo.data.length;
                            var dateFindIndex = -1, d = null;
                            (isAllowToConcat === false) ? sharedDataByDate.data = [] : "";
                            if (sharedDataPhotoLength > 0) {
                                var photos_ = (!!photos) ? photos : sharedData.photo.data;
                                angular.forEach(photos_, function (value, index) {
                                    d = new Date(value.created_at).toDateString();
                                    dateFindIndex = IsDateExists(d);
                                    if (dateFindIndex === -1) {
                                        var tempObj = {date: d, data: []};
                                        sharedDataByDate.data.push(tempObj);
                                        dateFindIndex = IsDateExists(d);
                                    }
                                    sharedDataByDate.data[dateFindIndex].data.push(value);
                                    //console.log("<br/>Row index : " + index + "<br/>>> data length : " + dataLength + "<br/>>> datefindIndex : " + datefindIndex + "<br/>>> Date to find : " + d);
                                });
                            }
                            return sharedDataByDate;
                        };
                        var getSharedDataByDate = function () {
                            return sharedDataByDate;
                        };
                        var IsDateExists = function (date) {
                            var sharedDataByDateLength = sharedDataByDate.data.length;
                            for (var index = 0; index < sharedDataByDateLength; index++) {
                                if (date === sharedDataByDate.data[index].date) {
                                    return index;
                                }
                            }
                            return -1;
                        };
                        var setInlinePopupContent = function (data) {
                            /*
                             * Create an array of magnific inline popup content
                             */
                            var index = 0;
                            angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                                if (value.data.length > 0) {
                                    var loopIndex = 0;
                                    angular.forEach(value.data, function (value_, key_) {
                                        arrData.push({
                                            imageDescriptionDiv: ("" === value_.photo_description) ? "Description writes here" : value_.photo_description,
                                            imageDescriptionHidden_value: value_.photo_description,
                                            //imageDescriptionTxtArea: value_.photo_description,
                                            //imageScale_img: "/resize/" + value_.module + "/" + value_.photo_name,
                                            //imageOriginal_href: "/" + value_.module + "/" + value_.photo_name,
                                            imageScale_img: $rootScope.app_dir.resize_730_730 + "photo/" + value_.photo_name,
                                            imageOriginal_href: $rootScope.app_dir.web_path + "photo/" + value_.photo_name,
                                            imageIden_value: value_._id,
                                            imageTxtDescription_id: value_._id,
                                            imageIndex_value: index,
                                            imageYear_value: value.year,
                                            imageYearIndex_value: loopIndex
                                        });
                                        loopIndex++;
                                        index++;
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        };
                        var getInlinePopupContent = function () {
                            return arrData;
                        }

                        return {
                            setSharedData: setSharedData,
                            getSharedData: getSharedData,
                            setSharedEmojis: setSharedEmojis,
                            getSharedEmojis: getSharedEmojis,
                            setSharedDataByDate: setSharedDataByDate,
                            getSharedDataByDate: getSharedDataByDate,
                            IsDateExists: IsDateExists,
                            setInlinePopupContent: setInlinePopupContent,
                            getInlinePopupContent: getInlinePopupContent
                        };
                    }
                ]);
    }());
    > HzServices.js

    (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular
                .module("AppDream")
                .factory("HzServices", ['$rootScope', '$http', '$cacheFactory', '$q', '$location', 'notifications',
                    function ($rootScope, $http, $cacheFactory, $q, $location, notifications) {
                        return {
                            /**
                             * Common $q reponse
                             * @param {type} url
                             * @param {type} method
                             * @param {type} data
                             * @returns {object}
                             * @description Common method to get ajax response via $q api
                             */
                            deferred: function (url, method, data) {
                                var req = {
                                    method: method,
                                    url: url,
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': "application/json"
                                    },
                                    cache: false
                                };
                                if ("GET" === method.toUpperCase()) {
                                    req.params = data;
                                } else if ("POST" === method.toUpperCase()) {
                                    req.data = data;
                                } else {
                                    req.data = "";
                                }

                                var deferred = $q.defer();
                                $http(req)
                                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                            deferred.resolve(data);
                                        })
                                        .error(function (data, status) {
                                            deferred.reject(data);
                                        });
                                return deferred.promise;
                            },
                            /**
                             * Return default media folder by photos, videos
                             * @param {String} media
                             * @returns {undefined}
                             */
                            getDefaultMediaFolder: function (media) {
                                switch (media) {
                                    case "photo":
                                        return "wall photos";
                                        break;
                                    case "video":
                                        return "wall photos";
                                        break;
                                }
                            },
                            getAppUrl: function () {
                                switch ($location.host()) {
                                    case "node.dream.com":
                                        return $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + ":3030";
                                        break;
                                    case "staging.dream.com":
                                        return $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + ":3131";
                                        break;
                                    case "dream.com":
                                        return $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + ":1010";
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        return $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + ":" + $location.port();
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                ]);
    }());
```

Comment: FYI - this is all handled on the client, nothing on the server. If you want to prevent sending multiple requests, then check if you have already sent a request (and haven't received a response from it) before sending another one. If you want to send multiple requests, `abort()` any previous active request.

Comment: @Adam: I know it.. it handles from client but I don't know actually how to implement in angluarjs.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us your code and what you have tried

Comment: ok Let me edit and know you.

Comment: @Adam : please check my question again.

Comment: @Weedoze :  Please check my question again

Comment: @Dipakchavda http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel angular service ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997604/how-to-cancel-angular-service-ajax-request)